# Laravel Blade ( Displaying data as new line)

Tags: php, laravel, newline, laravel-blade

So i have a `<textarea>` in my form. User can either enter a new line or single line. So when the user views the text it will be showed like how he/she inputs it.

Form

```
<textarea name="jo_unit" class = 'form-control' required="required" cols = '4'></textarea>
```

**Expected Output**

TESTING 1
 TESTING 2
 TESTING 3

**What i get**

[image: What i get]

**My code on displaying it**

```
{{ nl2br(@$get['result'][0]->jo_unit_2) }}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Security: This code allows XSS attacks and is not production ready.

use `{!! !!}`:

```
{!! nl2br(@$get['result'][0]->jo_unit_2) !!}
```

Comment: Can i ask why it is needed to use the `!!` and what does that stands for ?

Comment: beacuse Blade `{{ }}` statements are automatically sent through PHP's htmlentities function to prevent XSS attacks but `{!! !!}` not

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
{!! nl2br(e(@$get['result'][0]->jo_unit_2)) !!}
```

`{!! !!}` creates an escaped output and allows HTML (and XSS attacks).

To make it secure again you also need to use `e()` see [helpers documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers#method-e).